# WordPressで構築したサイトのドメインを変更したら、固定ページやブログにアクセスできなくなりました

Tags: wordpress

ご閲覧感謝します。

ロリポップにWordPressを入れてサイトを構築し、
題名の通り、ドメインを変更したところ、トップページ以外のページにアクセスできなくなりました。

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at https://lolipop.jp/support/ to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

一般設定のWordPressアドレスは変えず、サイトアドレスだけ新しいドメインにしました。

phpmyadminのpostsテーブルではguidが古いURLのままで疑わしいと思い更新してみましたが、アクセスできないままです。
何を修正すれば直るでしょうか

Comment: アクセスできないとは具体的にどのような動作になりますか？40X系のエラーが出る？WordPressのエラー画面になる？

Comment: @keitaro_so ありがとうございます！エラーはInternal Server Errorです！質問も修正しました。

Comment: 500番ということはApacheなどのWebサーバでエラーが起きているかもしくはPHPのエラーが起きている可能性があります。エラーメッセージにある通りエラーログの確認はできますか？

Comment: @keitaro_so すみません、解決しました。原因は.htaccessでした、ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` が原因でした！
以下のサイトを参考に `.htaccess` を修正したところ、問題なく動作しました！

[WordPressドメイン設定後にInternal Server Error](https://www.bonchi-hita.com/archives/894.html)